# nth smallest number with n bits set to 1

Tags: c, algorithm, bit

There is a sequence of increasing numbers that have the same number of binary 1s in them. Given n (the number of 1 bits set in each number in the series) write an algorithm or C program to find the n'th number in the series.

I found this question on internet and I think the answer is just (((1 << (n+1)) - 1) & ~2). Isn't that right? I found some scary programs to compute the answer.

Comment: It shouldn't be hard to write a program to verify that!

Comment: Are the two `n` variables the same?  In other words, is the question "if each number has 5 ones, find the fifth such number?"

Comment: You can use http://realtimecollisiondetection.net/blog/?p=78 to verify it.

Comment: @ruslik - thanks. That cleared up.

Comment: Your answer looks fine to me.  The question is a bit ambiguous as to whether this sequence contains ALL of the n-1-bit numbers, or some (unspecified) subset of them.

Comment: Did you really mean to use both n = number of bits and n = which one to select?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`(1 << n+1) - 3` is a more concise way to express the result, but yes, I believe your expression is also correct.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's true. When we have 3 bits:

```
1:  00000111
2:  00001011
3:  00001101 // bit 1 will be 0
4:  00001110
```

so the answer is n+1 bits, where bit 1 is 0.

Comment: His formula, for n=3, gives 13. This is the number you list in line 3, so his formula looks right to me. krakover's formula is incorrect.

Comment: No ruslik, in this case my expression will yield 00001101 - won't it? (((1 << 4) - 1) & (11111101)) = 00001101

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are right. <strike>A simpler way to write it though will be: 
((1 << n) - 1) << 1.</strike>

Comment: No, this expression is not equivalent to mine.

Answer (score -1):

The question doesn't seem to specify where the sequence begins, or how much the number will increase each time, whereas your answer appears to assume that the sequence will start with 011111, then move to 101111, and so on. It could conceivably start with 0011111000, and the next element could be 1111100000.

**Edit**

The question, as stated at https://groups.google.com/group/algogeeks/browse_thread/thread/5fda06c0be475c41/ is titled, "nth number of the series", so the title of this post ("nth smallest number with n bits set to 1") isn't really in keeping the the question's origin.

Comment: No: for 5 bits, 11111 is clearly a number in the sequence, and it is clearly smaller than 0011111000. So the sequence can't start with 0011111000.

Comment: It's the nth smallest integer with n bits set to 1. To be more specific it should have been unsigned integer.

Comment: The question states, "There is a sequence of increasing numbers that have the same number of binary 1s in them." It doesn't tell you that the sequence must start with the smallest possible number. It's not the same as saying "Sequence S is defined as all positive numbers with the same number of binary 1s in them, in ascending order."

Comment: @Anil Katti: Was it defined that way in the question you read online, or is that just how you understood it?

Comment: @ StriplingWarrior, the question that I found did not have "smallest" in it. I added it when I posted it here since it made more sense.