# Find rank of a number on basis of number of 1's

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

Let f(k) = y where k is the y-th number in the increasing sequence of non-negative integers with
the same number of ones in its binary representation as k, e.g. f(0) = 1, f(1) = 1, f(2) = 2, f(3) = 1, f(4)
= 3, f(5) = 2, f(6) = 3 and so on. Given k >= 0, compute f(k)

many of us have seen this question

1 solution to this problem to categorise numbers on basis of number of 1's and then find the rank.i did find some patterns going by this way but it would be a lengthy process. can anyone suggest me a better solution?

Comment: @harold: could you explain your answer with giving an example?

Comment: Are you sure you got the definition of `f` right? Take `y = 1`. That has one `1` in its binary expansion, so the sequence is `1`, `10, `100`, etc. How can both `f(0)` and `f(1)` be `1`?

Comment: @KerrekSB: I think, you misunderstood it.

Comment: `same number of ones in its binary representation as y` - I believe you mean *"same number of ones in its binary representation as **k**"*?

Comment: @KerrekSB: this is not the question.. f(k) gives rank. f(0)=1 means that 0 has 1st rank among those which has 0 1's in binary repres. , f(1)=1 means 1 has 1st rank among this which has got only one 1's and so on..

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft: Yes. You're right. In fact, I read it `k` even though it was written `y`. Because `k` makes sense, but `y` doesn't.

Comment: @pravs: it's the question you *asked*, just not the question you meant to ask. Edited.

Comment: The "number of 1's in the number" is called its "rank."  People are getting confused because you are using the term "rank" to mean something else (its position in a list).

Comment: possible duplicate of [nth smallest number with n bits set to 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599501/nth-smallest-number-with-n-bits-set-to-1)

Answer (score 10):

This is a counting problem. I think that if you approach it with this in mind, you can do much better than literally enumerating values and checking how many bits they have.

Consider the number 17. The binary representation is 10001. The number of 1s is 2. We can get smaller numbers with two 1s by (in this case) re-distributing the 1s to any of the four low-order bits. 4 choose 2 is 6, so 17 should be the 7th number with 2 ones in the binary representation. We can check this...

```
   0 00000 -
   1 00001 -
   2 00010 -
   3 00011 1
   4 00100 -
   5 00101 2
   6 00110 3
   7 00111 -
   8 01000 -
   9 01001 4
  10 01010 5
  11 01011 -
  12 01100 6
  13 01101 -
  14 01110 -
  15 01111 -
  16 10000 -
  17 10001 7
```

And we were right. Generalize that idea and you should get an efficient function for which you simply *compute* the rank of k.

EDIT: Hint for generalization
17 is special in that if you don't consider the high-order bit, the number has rank 1; that is, f(z) = 1 where z is everything except the higher order bit. For numbers where this is not the case, how can you account for the fact that you can get smaller numbers without moving the high-order bit?

Comment: by your algo rank of 5 and 6 is coming same i.e 3C2.i have already tried this combination method but it does not work for every case. could you give some idea?

Comment: @pravs: See my "hint for generalization". The method definitely works, but you need to consider an additional term when the number sans high-order bit is not of rank 1 itself. Additional hint: In the case of the number 12, we can get 3C2 numbers the way you mention, but we can also get 3 numbers by simply moving the second 1 around... and it just so happens that the rank of 100 is 3. 3 + 3 = 6, the rank of 12... coincidence, or something more?

Answer (score 4):

f(k) are integers less than or equal to k that have the same number of ones in their binary representation as k.

For example, k needs m bits, that is `k = 2^(m-1) + a`, where `a < 2^(m-1)`. The number of integers less than `2^(m-1)` that have the same number of bits as k is `choose(m-1, bitcount(k))`, since you can freely redistribute the ones among the `m-1` least significant bits.

Integers that are greater than or equal to 2^(m-1) have the same most significant bit as k (which is 1), so there are `f(k - 2^(m-1))` of them. This implies `f(k) = choose(m-1, bitcount(k)) + f(k-2^(m-1))`.

Comment: Not sure why the -1, this is a great answer (though it could use some better formatting).

Comment: Yes, totally. It's a very good explanation - only badly formatted.

Comment: Yeah, not sure why this got down-voted. This is essentially my solution with the extra "hint" term solved for.

Answer (score -1):

See ["Efficiently Enumerating the Subsets of a Set"](http://applied-math.org/subset.pdf).    Look at Table 3, the "Bankers sequence".  This is a method to generate exactly the sequence you need (if you reverse the bit order).  Just run K iterations for the word with K bits. There is code to generate it included in the paper.