# Find rank of a decimal number based on function F( N ) = rank

Tags: c, performance, algorithm, bit-manipulation, time-complexity

I found this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7932558/find-rank-of-a-number-on-basis-of-number-of-1s), but this is not the answer i am looking for. Hence, posting again.

A function of the form:

```
F( N ) = rank
```

means that Given a number `N` in decimal representation, its rank is given as:

```
Starting from 0 to N, how many numbers are there with same number of set bits in its
binary representation.
```

I will go through an example to make it more clear.

```
N = 6 ( 0110 )
Its rank is 3.
1. 3 ( 0011 )
2. 5 ( 0101 )
3. 6 ( 0110 )
```

Now, given a number, find its rank.

The obvious approach is to start from 0 and check for number of set bits for each number till `N-1`.

The question is:

Is there any logN solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is a `log n` solution.

Let `n` have `k` bits set, the most significant bit being in position `p` (starting to count positions from 0, so `2^p <= n < 2^(p+1)`). Then there are `pCk` (binomial coefficient, also `choose(p,k)`) ways to place `k` bits in the positions `0, ..., p-1`, all these give numbers with exactly `k` set bits that are smaller than `n`. If `k == 1`, that's it, otherwise there remain the numbers with `k` set bits and the `p`-th bit set that are smaller than `n` to consider. Those can be counted by determining the rank of `n - 2^p`.

Code (not optimal, does some unnecessary recomputation, and doesn't all that it could do to avoid overflow):

```
unsigned long long binom(unsigned n, unsigned k) {
    if (k == 0 || n == k) return 1;
    if (n < k) return 0;
    if (k > (n >> 1)) k = n-k;
    unsigned long long res = n, j;
    // We're not doing all we can to avoid overflow, as this is a proof of concept,
    // not production code.
    for(j = 2; j <= k; ++j) {
        res *= (n+1-j);
        res /= j;
    }
    return res;
}

unsigned popcount(unsigned long long n) {
    unsigned k = 0;
    while(n) {
        ++k;
        n &= (n-1);
    }
    return k;
}

unsigned long long rank(unsigned long long n) {
    if (n == 0) return 1;
    unsigned p = 0, k = popcount(n);
    unsigned long long mask = 1,h = n >> 1;
    while(h > 0) {
        ++p;
        h >>= 1;
    }
    mask <<= p;
    unsigned long long r = binom(p,k);
    r += rank(n-mask);
    return r;
}
```

Tested in a loop for `0 <= n < 10^8` to check for mistakes without any mismatch found.

Check output [here](http://ideone.com/159HJ).

Comment: For reference, `pCk` refers to the [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient).

Comment: The approach looks fine. But, did you check for N = 5 & N = 6? It fails here.

Comment: @Aashish I haven't done all the details yet, give me a couple of minutes to write some code ;)

Comment: @DanielFischer: [puts on OEIS Editor hat] If you do work out the details, you could add it as a comment to A068076; I'll review it myself.

Comment: @DSM Details worked out, A068076 is `rank(n)-1`. But how do I add a comment on OEIS? Would I have to register there?

Comment: @DanielFischer: yeah (link on the main page).  After that, when you log in, an "edit" button appears above an entry.  You make changes, semi-Wiki-style, and then propose them (another button).  Then they're reviewed by the editors, and eventually approved by one of the Editors-in-Chief like me.

Comment: @DanielFischer how is the time complexity lg n here ?

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved by combination and permutation techniques.

F(N) = rank

First find number of bits that are required to represent N. In binary representation, number can be constructed as follows:

```
N = cn 2^n + .... + c3 2^2 + c2 2^1 + c1 2^0
```

Now, in order to find `n` (or numbers of bits in binary representation of a number) in above equation, we can assume that it will be `floor(log2(N)) + 1`. For example, consider any number, let say `118` then it can be represented by floor(log2(118)) + 1 = 7 bits.

```
n = floor(log2(118)) + 1;
```

Above formula is only `O(1)`. Now, we need to find how many 1s are there in binary representation of a number. Considering a pseudo-code to do this job:

```
function count1(int N) {
    int c = 0;
    int N' = N;

    while(N' > 0) {
       N' -= 2^(floor(log2(N')));
       c++;
    }
}
```

Above pseudo-code is `O(logN)`. I wrote small script in MATLAB to test my above pseudo-code and here are the results.

```
count1(6)   = 2
count1(3)   = 2
count1(118) = 5
```

Perfect, now we have number of bits and number of 1s in those bits. Now, simple combination and permutation can be applied to find the rank of number. first lets assume, `n` is number of bits required to represent a  number and `c` is number of 1s in the bit representation of a number. Therefore, rank would be given by:

```
r = n ! / c ! * (n - c) !
```

EDIT: As suggested by DSM, I've corrected the logic to find the correct RANK. Idea is to remove all the unwanted numbers from the permutation. So added this code:

```
for i = N + 1 : 2^n - 1
    if count(i) == c
       r = r - 1;
    end
end
```

I've written a MATLAb script to find rank of a number using above method:

```
function r = rankN(N)

n = floor(log2(N)) + 1;
c = count(N);
r = factorial(n) / (factorial(c) * factorial(n - c));
% rejecting all the numbers may have included in the permutations 
% but are unnecessary.
for i = N + 1 : 2^n - 1
    if count(i) == c
       r = r - 1;
    end
end

function c = count(n)

c = 0;
N = n;
while N > 0
    N = N - 2^(floor(log2(N)));
    c = c + 1;
end
```

And above alogrithm is `O(1) + O(logN) + O(1) = O(logN)`. The output is:

```
>> rankN(3)

ans =

     1

>> rankN(4)

ans =

     3

>> rankN(7)

ans =

     1

>> rankN(118)

ans =

    18

>> rankN(6)

ans =

     3
```

Note: Rank of `0` is always `1` because above method will fail for `0` as `log2(0)` is undefined.

Comment: How can `rankN(3)` be 2?  It's `11` in binary; the only number <= 3 with 2 bits is 3 itself.  I would think 3,4,7, 118 would have ranks of 1,3,1,18.

Comment: Yeah, there was some mistakes in my script, but output now is coming out to be [1, 3, 1, 21]

Comment: I'm pretty sure rank(118) is only 18.  I think you're counting numbers with the same number of bits as 118 from 119-128 too.

Comment: Binary representation of 118 is `1110110` 7 bits and it contains 5 - 1s and 2 - 0s, so `7 ! / 5 ! * 2 ! = 21` which matches with my script. Now, problem is narrowed down to whether my permutation formula is correct or not? What do you think?

Comment: You're forgetting that `1111001`, `1111010`, and `1111100` are valid permutations, but invalid numbers, because they're all larger than 118.  That's why you get 21 when the answer is 18.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me out..I just corrected my approach further.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rather efficient O(logN) implementation that performs multiple additions in parallel per step:

```
unsigned int countBits( unsigned int bits )
{
    bits = ( bits & 0x55555555 ) + ( ( bits >> 1 ) & 0x55555555 );
    bits = ( bits & 0x33333333 ) + ( ( bits >> 2 ) & 0x33333333 );
    bits = ( bits + ( bits >>  4 ) ) & 0x0f0f0f0f;
    bits += bits >>  8;
    return ( bits + ( bits >> 16 ) ) & 63;
}
```

It starts with 16 2-bit additions, then makes 8 4-bit additions and so on. It can be extended to work with 64-bit integers by using longer masks and one additional step:

```
unsigned int countBits( unsigned long long bits )
{
    bits = ( bits & 0x5555555555555555L ) + ( ( bits >> 1 ) & 0x5555555555555555LL );
    bits = ( bits & 0x3333333333333333L ) + ( ( bits >> 2 ) & 0x3333333333333333LL );
    bits = ( bits + ( bits >>  4 ) ) & 0x0f0f0f0f0f0f0f0fLL;
    bits += bits >>  8;
    bits += bits >> 16;
    return (unsigned int) ( bits + ( bits >> 32 ) ) & 127;
}
```